# Trying to merge Cells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, merge

Can anyone explain to me why this wont work?

```
Worksheets("Print_page").Range("2:2,2:7").Merge
```

Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

I am trying to merge columns B:F on row 2 and I can't figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're confusing `Range` and `Cells` syntax, though all you need is:

```
Worksheets("Print_page").Range("B2:F2").Merge
```

If you want to use `Cells`:

```
With Worksheets("Print_page")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(2, 7)).Merge
End With
```

Comment: is there a way to do this with numbers? I am using a count and find function to get my cell and column locations.

Comment: it works great! I didn't know you could put Cells into a range, this will be very helpful with future programming, thanks. I'll mark the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
    Range("2:3").Merge '<~~ row merge row 2, 3
    Range("b:c").Merge '<~~ column merge b,c

    Cells.UnMerge '<~~ cells unmerge

    Range("b2:f2").Merge '<~ specific range merge
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't try this but it makes logical sense I should have thought of it. Thank you for responding so quickly.